# Showing that $\pi_1(SO_n(\mathbb{C}))\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n>2$ and $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is connected.

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

$(1)$ Let's show that $\pi_1(SO_n(\mathbb{C}))\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n>2$. I want to prove this by induction using exact sequence of homotopy groups i.e. if we consider a transitive action of $SO_n(\mathbb{C})$ on a complex sphere $S^{n}\subset\mathbb{C}^n$, then we have
$$\pi_2(S^{n})\to \pi_1(SO_{n-1}(\mathbb{C}))\to\pi_1(SO_{n}(\mathbb{C}))\to \pi_1(S^{n}) .$$
So, we have that $\pi_1(SO_{n-1}(\mathbb{C}))\cong\pi_1(SO_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ if $n>2$ as $\pi_i(S^{j})=0$ for $i<j$. Since $\pi_1(SO_{3}(\mathbb{C}))\cong \mathbb{Z_2}$, then the desired follows.

I have some concerns that I am considering complex sphere $S^n$ because the concept of the fundamental group is applied when $S^n$ is real. So, do I repeat a similar argument try to embed $SO_n(\mathbb{C})$ in $GL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the action on a $(2n-1)$-dimensional sphere $S^{2n-1}$? Or, can I avoid that by doing something smart?

$(2)$ Is there a nice way for a given $A,B\in GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$, where $\det(A)>0$ and $\det(B)>0$, to find a path $\gamma(t):I\to GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $\gamma(0)=A$ and $\gamma(1)=B$ s.t. $\det(\gamma(t))>0$ for all $t$? I have two ideas:

1. $\gamma_1(t)=tB+(1-t)A$, $t\in [0,1],$
2. $\gamma_2(t)=B^tA^{1-t}$, $t\in [0,1].$

For the first one, I have a path, but I don't know how to show that $\det(\gamma_1(t))>0$ for all $t$. For the second one, I can define $\gamma_2(t)$ rigorously on $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, but what the argument do I need to use if I want to define the path on $[0,1]$ i.e. how to think about $A^t$ rigorously where $t\in[0,1]$?

Thank you!